# Как в Word interop получить текст из textbox?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Получаю textbox как Word.ContentControl, как отсюда получить текст "[MEGATEXTBOX]"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var text = control.Range.Text;

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]